# type void is not assignable to type any

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code in my component

```
export class AddNewCardComponent { 

    public concept = [];
    constructor( 
        private _router: Router,
        private _empDiscService: empDiscService) { 

        }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.concept = this._empDiscService.StoreMaster()
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            this.concept =  data;
        });
    }
}
```

its just i want to get var from services and put it in my store = [];

but it says

> type void is not assignable to type any

here is my code in services

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Httpprovider } from './httpprovider';

@Injectable()
export class empDiscService{

    public storedata = [];
    constructor(private _httpprovider: Httpprovider){

    }

    StoreMaster():Observable<any[]>{
        return this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getconcept','GET',null,null).map(res =>{<any[]>res.json()}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not `subscribe()` inside the service and return the object directly, which is not the intention of **RxJs**.

```
export class empDiscService{

    public storedata = [];
    constructor(private _httpprovider: Httpprovider){

    }
    StoreMaster():Observable<any[]>{
       return this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getmapmasterstore','GET',null,null).map(res =>{<any[]>res.json()}
    }

}
```

Your component should be

```
constructor( 
        private _router: Router,
        private _empDiscService: empDiscService) { 
          this.store = this._empDiscService.StoreMaster()
            .subscribe((data)=>{
                    this.storedata =  data;
        });
}
```

The actual mistake which you made is the service method was not returning anything

```
StoreMaster():Observable<any[]>{}
```

This will fix your problem

Comment: i got an error Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in my component do i need to import anything??

Comment: @Rommy return statement was missing in the `StoreMaster()` function. check the updated one

Comment: i try yours, there is some error on the component, when we do subcribe data, and now there is something new, i got this erro  >user Array.slice is not a function any idea?

Comment: where have I return Array.Slice in my code.. check in your code.

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Obsrvable'`

Comment: yeah thanks that part solve, but why when i'm still got error array.slice? Even though there is no slice in my code...

Comment: it is a slice method. search in complete project, some where it will be there.

Comment: well my bad, there is some misstype there, now its show error on res.json is not a function

Comment: Your `.map` callback is broken just like in the OP because it fails to syntactically return a value

Answer (score 3):

```
import { JobService } from './../services/job.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-job-list',
  templateUrl: './job-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-list.component.css']
})
export class JobListComponent implements OnInit {

 **jobs:any = [];**
erreur = '';
  constructor( private jobservice:JobService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobservice.getJobs().subscribe(

      data => this.jobs = data,
      error => {console.log ('error')}

    );


  }

}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I add type any on my variable.

Comment: Instead of comment your answer you can add to the answer that description text, to improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

`StoreMaster()` method does not return anything. You might need to change the service method to return the observable:

```
StoreMaster(){
return this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getmapmasterstore','' +
  '  GET',null,null).subscribe((data)=>{
  var brData = [];
  for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    brData.push(data[i]);
  }
  return brData;
});
}
```

and `ngOnInit`

```
    ngOnInit(){
        this._empDiscService.StoreMaster()
            .subscribe(store => this.store = store);
    }
```

Comment: i got an error Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined, well do i need to import anything?